# Get String text which is wrapped in a object

Tags: java, oop, dependency-injection, domain-driven-design, inversion-of-control

I want to create objects of a class which hold a specific string value. The string value will be passed through the constructor of the class, like this

```
public class Class_A {

   private String id;
   
   public Class_A (String id) {
      this.id = id;
   }
}
```

`Class_A` is a class in my core package.
Now I have `Class_B`, which is a class in my service package.
`Class_B` holds a function for creating a list of `Class_A` objects with individual strings.

How I can get the specific string value of each `Class_A` object when I access the list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can provide a get method for the string.

```
public class Class_A {

   private String id;
   
   public Class_A (String id) {
      this.id = id;
   }

   public String getId(){
      return id;
   }

   public String toString(){
     return id;
   }
}
```

Comment: i've tried it before and somehow it gives me back my string + pathway to the class in my project, like:  ```mystringPathwayToClass_A@5d5d9e5```
Why is it getting concatenated?

Comment: @FloatingGoat Can you show the way you access the list item that gives you this string?

Comment: @FloatingGoat I think you are calling the method toString().  In that case, you need to override toString() to return id.  I updated the code.

Comment: yea the override does the job, thanks you very much!